# Drools KIE workbench 7: error when saving kmodule.xml file in 'Knowledge Base Settings' page

Tags: drools, kie-workbench

In drools KIE workbench 7, for a project 'testRemoteKJar', I use 'Knowledge Base Settings:Knowledge bases an sessions' to edit its kmodule.xml, as in below screen shot.

[Screen Shot--Knowledge Base Settings.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkpYy.png)

When I click button 'save' to save kmodule.xml, the console of the KIE workbench print below error message.

> 08-Jul-2017 19:29:00.161 INFO [Thread-12] org.guvnor.common.services.builder.ResourceChangeIncrementalBuilder.updateResource Incremental build request received for: default://master@repo-demorules/testRemoteKJar/src/main/resources/META-INF/kmodule.xml (updated).
>
> 08-Jul-2017 19:29:00.317 INFO [Thread-607] org.guvnor.common.services.builder.ResourceChangeIncrementalBuilder$3.execute Incremental build request being processed: PathImpl{uri='default://master@repo-demorules/testRemoteKJar', fileName='testRemoteKJar', attrs={}} (updated).
>
> 08-Jul-2017 19:29:00.325 SEVERE [Thread-13] org.kie.workbench.common.screens.impl.LibraryIndexer.fillIndexBuilder Unable to index default://master@repo-demorules/testRemoteKJar/src/main/resources/META-INF/kmodule.xml: package could not be resolved.
>
> 08-Jul-2017 19:29:00.726 SEVERE [Thread-607] org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.AbstractKieModule.buildKnowledgePackages Unable to build KieBase, could not find include: kbase1

And if I download the jar file 'testRemoetKJar' from KIE workbench, the content of the kmodule.xml in that jar is just one line:

```
<kmodule xmlns="http://www.drools.org/xsd/kmodule" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
```

The error log contains words 'package could not be resolved', but the project 'testRemoteKJar' does have package 'org_care.crm.testremotekjar' (the package name is used in the screenshot above). So the error log should have other meaning.

How to fix the error? Thanks a lot.